# how combine between two arraylist if has same value

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

sorry if i confusing, i have two arraylist as below

```
al1 - [Consignment, Bank, Custodian, Rejected, Bank]
al2 - [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

1st element al2 is for 1st element al1, and so on

so my case is i have to check al1 there is any duplicate value, if have have combine the value in al2

so expected result is

```
al1 - [Consignment, Bank, Custodian, Rejected]
al2 - [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

i'm trying but would like to get fast solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a language agnostic question?

Comment: Please, use proper formatting, it will make your question more readable. And I second Felix about the language.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, thats why in the beginning of my question i write 'sorry if i confusing'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution shown below:

```
for( int i=0; i < al1.size(); i++ ){
    for( int j = al1.size()-1; j > i; j-- ){

        if( al1.get(i).equals(al1.get(j)) ){
            ArrayList temp1 = (ArrayList)al4.get(i);
            ArrayList temp2 = (ArrayList)al4.get(j);
            for(int k=0;k<temp1.size();k++){
                if(!temp2.get(k).equals("0")){
                    temp1.set(k, temp2.get(k));
                }
            }
            al1.remove(j);
            al4.remove(j);
            al4.set(i, temp1);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide a solution based on the nature of Set. Hope it helps.
new_alt1 and new_alt2 are the answers that you want.

```
HashSet dupTester = new HashSet();
ArrayList new_al1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList new_al2 = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i<alt2.size();i++){
        int lastSize = 0;
        dupTester.add(alt2.get(i));
                    if (dupTester.size() > lastSize) {
                        new_alt1.add(alt1.get(i));
                        new_alt2.add(alt2.get(i)); 
                    }  
                    lastSize = dupTester.size(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this instead. It is more code, but it is faster and easier to understand. Also recommend that you return the map instead of modifying the arrays as your initial problem states...

```
void combineDuplicates(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> b) {
  LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    ArrayList<Integer> existing = m.get(a.get(i));
    if (existing == null) { // not a repeat occurrence
      m.put(a.get(i), b.get(i));
    } else { // repeat occurrence; add newcomer to existing
      plusEquals(existing, b.get(i));
    }
  }
  // now we have the unique strings in order of occurrence associated
  // with int array so its time to unpack onto the parameters
  a.clear(); b.clear();
  for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> e : m.entrySet()) {
    a.add(e.getKey()); b.add(e.getValue());
  }
}

private void plusEquals(ArrayList<Integer> target, ArrayList<Integer> values) {
  assert target.size() == values.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < target.size(); ++i) {
    target.set( target.get(i) + values.get(i) );
  }
}
```